# Having trouble loading an .RDS file and knitting an Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am attempting to load an RDS file into an RMarkdown using the following code:

```
protests <- readRDS("protests.RDS")
```

and I get the error:

```
Error in gzfile(file, "rb") : cannot open the connection :
```

I had this file loaded before and it was working, but when I attempted to knit my RMarkdown I got the `Error while opening file: no such file or directory` notice

In attempting to fix that I typed the code to load the RDS file into the RMarkdown (it was previously in another document) and then it started giving me the above error. And then my code wouldn't work with that dataset.

I'e tried numerous ways to set the working directory and reload the file into R. Sometimes I can't get the file to load, sometimes it loads but gives me a *vec_size error* whenever I use the dataset, and sometimes the code works but my RMarkdown still won't know.

Currently I've got the dataset to load into the environment by typing the readRDS() into a different RMarkdown (but the readRDS() in my first RMarkdown still won't work despite being the exact same) and the code in the first RMarkdown in working, but it won't knit.

Does anybody have an idea what is going on?

Comment: Is your data in the same folder that your `.Rmd` file is?

Comment: Yes, .Rmd and the .RDS file are in the same folder.

Answer (score -1):

You have to put the readRDS() call in the

```
code chunk
```

Comment: in the setup chunk.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).